# Can I show a ul when clicking a button without using any CSS and having the exact same (visual) results?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, css-grid

In the responsive css of my web app, I'm trying to show the ul tag inside the "mobile header" only when clicking the "Connect Wallet" button.

I would like it to show and hide again as soon as clicking anything else.
Is it possible to achieve this without using any JS or Jquery?

Here is my code:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .grid-container,
  .media-mobile-vertical {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  body {
    background: #181923;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mobile-container {
    /* border: dotted 1px yellow; */
    display: grid;
    height: 95vh;
    padding: 2%;
  }
  .mobile-header {
    /* border: dotted 1px red; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .mob-header-left {
    /* border: dotted 3px green; */
    justify-items: start;
  }
  .mob-logo {
    max-width: 40%;
  }
  .mob-header-right {
    display: grid;
    /* border: dotted 3px blue; */
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-self: end;
    /* margin-right: 10%; */
  }
  .mob-header-right-dropdown-outer {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .mob-btn {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    min-height: 35px;
    min-width: 150px;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mob-sp {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mob-btn:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e92e6, #60fbd0 75%, #1c6599 150%);
    background-size: 300% 100%;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    color: #22242f;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .mob-header-right-dropdown {
    /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  .btn,
  .btn-blank-sidebar,
  .btn-grey {
    max-height: 35px;
    max-width: 15%;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  .mob-nobull {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link media="screen and (max-device-width: 500px)" rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css" />
  <link media="screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1024px)" rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="global0.ico" />
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mobile-header">
    <div class="mob-header-left">
      <img class="mob-logo" src="global1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="mob-header-right">
      <div class="mob-header-right-dropdown-outer">
        <button class="mob-btn btn-drop-right mob-btn-grey">
            <span>Connect Wallet</span>
          </button>
        <div class="mob-header-right-dropdown">
          <ul class="nobull">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Metamask</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Wallet Connect</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Binance Wallet</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Trust Wallet</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- MOBILE HEADER ENDS -->
</body>

</html>
```

How can I hide and show only on click the ul inside the "Connect Wallet"?

Comment: No, you need javascript if you want to hide your element on click of another element. I found a tutorial on that matter: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-hide-element-when-clicked-outside

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Maybe not the best solution in terms of accessibility, or touch screen (need to test it). But it's possible.

What you have to do is to control the dropdown visibility in function of button focus. And also in funcion of the dropdown focus itself, to permit keyboard navigation.

See the snippet below, I've made two modifications in CSS, I identified by CHANGE 1 and CHANGE 2.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .grid-container,
  .media-mobile-vertical {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  body {
    background: #181923;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mobile-container {
    /* border: dotted 1px yellow; */
    display: grid;
    height: 95vh;
    padding: 2%;
  }
  .mobile-header {
    /* border: dotted 1px red; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .mob-header-left {
    /* border: dotted 3px green; */
    justify-items: start;
  }
  .mob-logo {
    max-width: 40%;
  }
  .mob-header-right {
    display: grid;
    /* border: dotted 3px blue; */
    max-width: 100%;
    justify-self: end;
    /* margin-right: 10%; */
  }
  .mob-header-right-dropdown-outer {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .mob-btn {
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    min-height: 35px;
    min-width: 150px;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mob-sp {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
  .mob-btn:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e92e6, #60fbd0 75%, #1c6599 150%);
    background-size: 300% 100%;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    color: #22242f;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .mob-header-right-dropdown {
    /* display: none; */
    /* [CHANGE 1] */
    /* Hidding without display none 
       This way, the solution works also with keyboard (tabbed) navigation */
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    
  }
  .btn,
  .btn-blank-sidebar,
  .btn-grey {
    max-height: 35px;
    max-width: 15%;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  .mob-nobull {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  /* [CHANGE 2] */
  /* While button have focus OR focus is inside dropdown */
  .mob-btn:focus + .mob-header-right-dropdown,
  .mob-header-right-dropdown:focus-within {
    opacity: 1;
    width: auto;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link media="screen and (max-device-width: 500px)" rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css" />
  <link media="screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1024px)" rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="global0.ico" />
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mobile-header">
    <div class="mob-header-left">
      <img class="mob-logo" src="global1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="mob-header-right">
      <div class="mob-header-right-dropdown-outer">
        <button class="mob-btn btn-drop-right mob-btn-grey">
            <span>Connect Wallet</span>
        </button>
        <div class="mob-header-right-dropdown">
          <ul class="nobull">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Metamask</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Wallet Connect</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Binance Wallet</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="mob-btn btn-grey btn-blank">
                <span class="mob-sp">Trust Wallet</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- MOBILE HEADER ENDS -->
</body>

</html>
```